# When i try find Index of char in arrray i get -1

Tags: c#

I am trying to code a simple app to let a user type a letter, and find out which position it is in in an Array, and than replace that position with the letter k.

I don`t know how to replace a char at a specific position, and the program give strange value of -1.

Thanks for any help.

Source code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Random r = new Random();
        string[] d = {"a" , "b" , "c" , "d" };

        string randomString= "";
        for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            randomString = randomString + d[r.Next(d.Length)];
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Debug: Random string output: " + randomString);

        char[] charArray = randomString.ToCharArray();
        Console.WriteLine("Type one char of random String to find postion of it:");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();
        int pos = Array.IndexOf(charArray , userinput);
        Console.WriteLine(userinput +" is at " + pos + ".");

        //Something to replace a char at that position with k 
         // Here display modified string with "k"
       Console.WriteLine(randomString); 
        Console.ReadLine();

        /*
         * Console output:
          Debug: Random string output: bbccb
           Type one char of random String to find postion of it:
           c  is at -1

        */

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) to see what that "strange value" means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(charArray , userinput);
```

You have an array of chars but you are searching a string
Change it to

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(charArray , userinput[0]);
```

Of course you should also check if the user types anything

Answer (score 0):

Your value `userinput` is a string, and hence a mismatch when compared to any single character in your array. You could get the first item in the string using `userinput[0]`, but if a user enters an empty string, then that will crash (an empty string has no valid "position 0").

Instead, try this:

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(charArray , userinput.FirstOrDefault());
```

That will return the first character if there is any; if not, it will return a `char` with a value of `00`, which will not match anything in your array, but also not cause the program to crash.

---

Oh, and one more thing: To replace a character at a specific position, just set the value for that position directly:

```
charArray[pos] = 'K'; // Will replace character at position pos.
```